# Wait for promise from father component from a children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a React application using the [Container/Presentational pattern](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) (a.k.a Smart/Dumb components).

Simply put what I have is a Presentational component that shows and hides a modal window. In the modal there's a form, once the user submits the form from the Presentational component I call the Container (via a prop). At this point, the Container makes an AJAX request.

To put it in a more visual way  this is what happens:

```
modal submit -> Presentational calls Container -> Container makes AJAX call
```

After the AJAX call is done I need to notify the Presentational component so that it can hide the modal.

The way I've implemented it is the following:

```
// In Presentational.jsx
handleModalSubmit() {
  this.props
  .onSubmit()
  .then(() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false }))
}

// In Container.jsx
handleSubmit () {
  return fetch(/*...*/).then(/* handle the data */)
}
```

You can see it in action here https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kl3oN5Hua4cxwmZx4Qo

My question is is it ok for a parent to return a promise to a child or is there a more Reactive way to do it?

Comment: I think its better to use Redux for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't necessarily anything wrong with what you're doing.

Another option would be to move the 'isModalOpen' state up into the parent component and then just pass it down into the child via a prop. At that point Presentational.jsx is truly a presentantational component. Typically when talking about smart/dumb or container/presentational components, all of the state lives in the parent and the dumb components just render based on props they receive.

The advantage here would be that your Presentational.jsx could now be used in situations where you don't want to use a promise when the modal is submitted. Moreover, you could have other logic that might also close the modal other than submitting it. So you're getting a component with greater reuse potential because it assumes less.

The tradeoff, however, is that because you assume less, your component no longer contains the logic for what is likely a common pattern in your app (submitting returns a promise and close the modal when the promise resolves). To get the best of both worlds, you could have your stateless component and then create a simple wrapper around it that contains the isModal state management you currently have. With the stateless and the stateful components, you can handle both the common case where you just want a modal to close on submit promise resolve and the case where you need something a bit different, but have it look the same.